# Aws Connection to EC2 timed out over SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have tried to connect EC2 using SSH but `ssh: connect to host XXXXXXXXX port 22: Connection timed out`

**Note:** XXXXXXXX is user@IP

Also I have checked `security groups`. Inbound rules are allowed for ssh

```
SSH TCP 22  0.0.0.0/0   -
SSH TCP 22  ::/0    -
```

For first time, I was able to login using SSH. After that I installed LAMP stack on EC2 instance. I think I forgot to add *ssh* in *ufw rules*.

I can't able to connect using Browser Based SSH Connection in AWS and showing erros for Session Manager connection method.

How can I connect using SSH or other, so I can allow SSH in ufw rules.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that you cannot to the host.

From your question I can see you have validated security group access, however there are some other steps you should take to investigate this:

- Is the IP address a public IP? If so ensure that the instances subnet has a route table with a Internet Gateway associated with it.
- Is the IP address a private IP? Do you have a [VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/) or [Direct Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/directconnect/) connection to the instance? If not you would either need to set this up or use a bastion host. Otherwise if you do ensure that the route tables reference back to your on premise network range.
- If you're not using the default [NACLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html) for your subnet check that both the port ranges from your security group as well as [ephemeral port ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports).